# Why the Wait() in idc script can not work on IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

In my IDC script I open a log file, do some analysis, write in the file and close the file like this:

```
main(){
open_log();
do_analysis();
close_log();
}
```

Currently I am using this script on command line, and I am trying to close the GUI after analysis(or be more exact, don't not open GUI while analyzing)

Here is command line I use:

```
"z:\ida6.1\idaq.exe -A -SfunctionEnumeration.idc z:\Linux\targetfile"
```

I modified my script like this:

```
main(){
open_log();
do_analysis();
close_log();

Wait();
Exit(0);
}
```

Currently it will generate the log file, but no content in it..

It seems that IDA Pro is closed before the write operation(or close operation)
on the log file, but I don't understand why because Wait() is called in my script...

I read the IDC manual and haven't find anything useful...

Could anyone give me some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
main(){
Wait();
open_log();
do_analysis();
close_log();
Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why does this work when the other does not?

Comment: @fileoffset: Wait() waits for IDA's auto-analysis to finish before continuing IDC code execution. The code in the question logged its data before auto-analysis was finished; the code in the answer logs its data *after* auto-analysis is finished by calling Wait() first.

Comment: Ahh, righto, makes sense. IDA's API is not what I would call intuitive :)